# How to allow file empty outside default controller?

Tags: validation, yii

I have two models `Quotation` and `order`. quotation and order both contain `file` attribute accepting only `emb,dst` file formats.Order and quotation both have their respective controllers. I want to copy quotation to order. The issue is that when i run this code

```
$order=new Order();
$order->file=$quotation->file;
```

It says `file cannot be blank`. 
here are my rules for Order

```
array('colours, width, height, is_inch, garment, file', 'required','on'=>'create'),
            array('is_inch', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('width, height', 'numerical'),
            array('colours, garment, file', 'length', 'max'=>255),
            array('user_id, quotation_id', 'length', 'max'=>10),
                    array('file','file','on'=>'update','allowEmpty'=>true),
                    array('file','file','types'=>'dst,emb'),
```

The issue is that i am not using order controller actions for above stated problem. 
**QUESTION:**
IS there any way to allow file empty for operations outside the order controller?

Answer (score 0):

you can use scenarios for that matter, you have already used a scenario and didn't realize that!

in your code

```
 array('colours, width, height, is_inch, garment, file', 'required','on'=>'create'),
```

all of those fields were required on create scenario, so you can remove that attribute and have another scenario like

```
 array('colours, garment', 'required','on'=>'noFile'),
```

then make your model with that scenario

```
$order=new Order('noFile');
```

then those rules should be applied

Comment: I have already tried this but its not working. I dont know whats wrong.